# LaTeX Horizontal Bar Chart, Gradient Color for Bars

Tags: graphics, color, bar-chart, gradient

I want to create a chart for ranking like this:

[image]

The top row shows the ranking (Poor - Excellent), and the left column shows the parameters. Now I want the bars to look like the figure, coloring with gradients based on the ranking value which is [0-100], 0 being **Poor**, 50 being **Average**, and 100 being **Excellent**. Poor ranking has red color, average ranking has yellow color, and top ranking has dark green color. The colors blend in the middle like a gradient smooth transition.

Is this doable? If yes, can anyone provide guidance? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept typesetting the data as a "normal" table together with some [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) code for the slider.

As suggested by the OP, using `Red` and `DarkGreen` (with `svgnames` in [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)), the result is:

[image]

This looks pretty ordinary and, in particular, there no sign of a yellow colour in the middle of the slider. I suspect that we will never see yellow in the middle of the slider if we use a gradient. I thought that the "standard colours" to use here would be from blue (cool) to red (hot). Using `Blue` and `Red` gives:

[image]

Here's another alternative with `Yellow` and `ForestGreen`:

[image]

Finally, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\Mark[2][8.4]{%
  \rlap{\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]{
        \shade[left color=Yellow, right color=ForestGreen!#2!Yellow]
               (0,0) rectangle ++(#1*#2/100,0.3);}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{rXXXXX}
   &\textsf{Poor}&\textsf{Low}&\textsf{Average}&\textsf{High}
   &\textsf{Excellent}\\[2mm]
   \textsf{Quality}       & \Mark{100}\\[-4mm]
   \textsf{Innovation}    & \Mark{70}\\[-4mm]
   \textsf{Ease} of use   & \Mark{10}\\[-4mm]
   \textsf{Accessibility} & \Mark{90}\\[-4mm]
   \textsf{Support}       & \Mark{84}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

A few comments:

- I used a [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment as this is the easiest way to make the columns have the same width
- The `X` columns inside a [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment do not play well with `\multicolumn` so I have used `\rlap{...}` to place the slider. In turn this does not play well with the row spacing so I have hacked this by adding manual adjustments of `\\[-4mm]` to the end of each row
- The `\Mark` command is used to create the colour sliders. The syntax for this command is `\Mark[optional length]{mark from 0-100}`.  By default the length of the slider is set to `8.4` units, which I got to by trial and error to make the slider length match the table width. The choice of colours are set inside the definition of the `\Mark` macro and so are easily customisable to suit your tastes:)

Comment: Thank you @Andres, that's exactly what i wanted..... Very detailed explanation and extremely helpful answer..... Highly appreciated.