# How can I create a stacked bar graph for a 5-scale Likert chart for every row in a table?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I want to create a table to represent the response from a survey as 5-scale Likert chart for every question. The table should like as follows. [[image: stacked bar sample table]

Comment: A previous question, [bar graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644953/pgf-plot-stacked-bar-graph-random-colors), used PGF plot to make a graph. This question benefit from a modified form of the example linked.

Comment: There this [bar graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455333/latex-horizontal-bar-chart-gradient-color-for-bars) example as well.

Comment: @Leucippus None of the answers discuss stacked bar graph or bar graph inside a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of graph is simple enough that you can draw it as a series of colored `\rule` commands. This command has two mandatory arguments: the length and the height. You can give the length as a macro argument and set the height fixed as 10pt for example. So you need a macro with five arguments, one for each line segment.

In the code below I added an optional first argument for the width of the full bar in terms of `\textwidth`, which is used for scaling with `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package. I have set the default value of this optional argument on `0.5\textwidth`, which is actually a bit too big for the margins so you should experiment with what a good default value would be for your document. The third row in the example below shows how to use the optional argument to get a smaller bar.

Then the line is built in a tabular with one row and three columns. The first column is the sum of the second and third argument, the third column is the sum of the fifth and sixth argument, and the middle column is a series of rules with as length the values of the second through sixth arguments.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\likertpct}[6][0.5]{%
\begin{tabular}{rcr}
\the\numexpr#2+#3\relax\% &
\resizebox{#1\textwidth}{\height}{%
\color{blue}\rule{#2mm}{10pt}\color{cyan}\rule{#3mm}{10pt}\color{lightgray}\rule{#4mm}{10pt}\color{yellow}\rule{#5mm}{10pt}\color{orange}\rule{#6mm}{10pt}%
} &
\the\numexpr#5+#6\relax\%\\
\end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
12 What do you think about unicorns? & \likertpct{12}{14}{8}{9}{57}\\
13 How important is pineapple on a pizza? & \likertpct{43}{44}{4}{4}{5}\\
14 How important is this bar? & \likertpct[0.3]{12}{14}{8}{9}{57}\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1em}
\textcolor{blue}{\rule{7pt}{7pt}} Very important %
\textcolor{cyan}{\rule{7pt}{7pt}} Important %
\textcolor{lightgray}{\rule{7pt}{7pt}} Moderately important %
\textcolor{yellow}{\rule{7pt}{7pt}} Slightly important %
\textcolor{orange}{\rule{7pt}{7pt}} Not important at all
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]